# MySQL PHP is not exporting large data to Excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to export an excel file from mysql table name **personen** which has 35 columns and it contain around 950+ records, if I export around 300 rows by using limit in the query it generates excel perfectly but when I try to export 500 rows and more it produces this in 0 byte excel file  [image]

**Here is my code**

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';  
require_once 'db_config.inc.php';
// Create new PHPExcel object  
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

// Set properties  
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")  
->setLastModifiedBy("Habib ul Haque")  
->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")  
->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")  
->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")  
->setCategory("Test result file");  



$rows=1;

//This is the hard coded *non dynamic* cell formatting
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('R')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('S')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('T')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('U')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('V')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('W')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('X')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Y')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('Z')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AA')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AB')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AC')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AD')->setWidth(5);  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AE')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AF')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AG')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AH')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AI')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('AJ')->setWidth(5);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(85);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.($rows+0),'Persoon-Id')
            ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+0),'Aanspreking')
            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+0),'VoorNaam')
            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+0),'Naam')
            ->setCellValue('E'.($rows+0),'Fonetisch')
            ->setCellValue('F'.($rows+0),'Extra Naam')
            ->setCellValue('G'.($rows+0),'Adres1')
            ->setCellValue('H'.($rows+0),'Adres2')
            ->setCellValue('I'.($rows+0),'Postcode')
            ->setCellValue('J'.($rows+0),'Plaats')
            ->setCellValue('K'.($rows+0),'Land')
            ->setCellValue('L'.($rows+0),'Taal')
            ->setCellValue('M'.($rows+0),'Tel1')
            ->setCellValue('N'.($rows+0),'Tel1-nota')
            ->setCellValue('O'.($rows+0),'Fax1')
            ->setCellValue('P'.($rows+0),'Fax1-nota')
            ->setCellValue('Q'.($rows+0),'Email1')
            ->setCellValue('R'.($rows+0),'Email1-nota')
            ->setCellValue('S'.($rows+0),'Tel2')
            ->setCellValue('T'.($rows+0),'Tel2-nota')
            ->setCellValue('U'.($rows+0),'Fax2')
            ->setCellValue('V'.($rows+0),'Fax2-nota')
            ->setCellValue('W'.($rows+0),'Email2')
            ->setCellValue('X'.($rows+0),'Email2-nota')
            ->setCellValue('Y'.($rows+0),'Nota-1')
            ->setCellValue('Z'.($rows+0),'Nota-2')
            ->setCellValue('AA'.($rows+0),'Mailing')
            ->setCellValue('AB'.($rows+0),'Datum-invoer')
            ->setCellValue('AC'.($rows+0),'Datum-laatste-wijziging')
            ->setCellValue('AD'.($rows+0),'Extra1')
            ->setCellValue('AE'.($rows+0),'Extra2')
            ->setCellValue('AF'.($rows+0),'Extra3')
            ->setCellValue('AG'.($rows+0),'Oude Publieksbestand-id')
            ->setCellValue('AH'.($rows+0),'Vantabel')
            ->setCellValue('AI'.($rows+0),'Correct Addres')
            ->setCellValue('AJ'.($rows+0),'Codes');
    //  SQl database connections
   /* $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "IMC_COE2", "IMC123");  
    mysql_select_db("IMC_COE2",$db);  
*/
    $mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die("couldnt connect to database".mysqli_connect_error());
    $sql="select * from personen";  
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);   
        if ($result->num_rows>0)  
        {  
         $i=1;
            while($data=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
            {  



        $query="select personselectiecodes.SelectieCode from personselectiecodes join personen on(personen.PersonId=personselectiecodes.PersonId) where personselectiecodes.PersonId=".$data['PersonId']."";
        $res=$mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);

        $codes=array();
            while ($row1=$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
            {
                if ($row1['SelectieCode']!="") 
                {
                    $codes[]=$row1['SelectieCode'];
                }
            }
        $str=implode(';',$codes);
                //This section is the actual data import fromt he SQL database *dont touch*
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)              
                            ->setCellValue('A'.($rows+$i), $data['PersonId']) //this will give cell C2. 
                            ->setCellValue('B'.($rows+$i), $data['Salutation']) // this will give cell B2 
                            ->setCellValue('C'.($rows+$i), $data['LastName']) //this will give C5 
                            ->setCellValue('D'.($rows+$i), $data['FirstName'])  // This will give D5
                            ->setCellValue('E'.($rows+$i), $data['Phonetical'])  //This will give C6
                            ->setCellValue('F'.($rows+$i), $data['ExtraName']) //This will give D6 etc...  
                            ->setCellValue('G'.($rows+$i), $data['Address1'])
                            ->setCellValue('H'.($rows+$i), $data['Address2'])
                            ->setCellValue('I'.($rows+$i), $data['PostalCode'])
                            ->setCellValue('J'.($rows+$i), $data['Area'])
                            ->setCellValue('K'.($rows+$i), $data['Country'])
                            ->setCellValue('L'.($rows+$i), $data['Language'])
                            ->setCellValue('M'.($rows+$i), $data['Tel1'])
                            ->setCellValue('N'.($rows+$i), $data['Tel1Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('O'.($rows+$i), $data['Fax1'])
                            ->setCellValue('P'.($rows+$i), $data['Fax1Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('Q'.($rows+$i), $data['Email1'])
                            ->setCellValue('R'.($rows+$i), $data['Email1Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('S'.($rows+$i), $data['Tel2'])
                            ->setCellValue('T'.($rows+$i), $data['Tel2Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('U'.($rows+$i), $data['Fax2'])
                            ->setCellValue('V'.($rows+$i), $data['Fax2Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('W'.($rows+$i), $data['Email2'])
                            ->setCellValue('X'.($rows+$i), $data['Email2Note'])
                            ->setCellValue('Y'.($rows+$i), $data['Note1'])
                            ->setCellValue('Z'.($rows+$i), $data['Note2'])
                            ->setCellValue('AA'.($rows+$i), $data['Mailing'])
                            ->setCellValue('AB'.($rows+$i), $data['InputDate'])
                            ->setCellValue('AC'.($rows+$i), $data['DateLastModified'])
                            ->setCellValue('AD'.($rows+$i), $data['Extra1'])
                            ->setCellValue('AE'.($rows+$i), $data['Extra2'])
                            ->setCellValue('AF'.($rows+$i), $data['Extra3'])
                            ->setCellValue('AG'.($rows+$i), $data['OldPublicFileId'])
                            ->setCellValue('AH'.($rows+$i), $data['FromTable'])
                            ->setCellValue('AI'.($rows+$i), $data['CorrectAddress']) 
                            ->setCellValue('AJ'.($rows+$i),$str);
                $i++;
                }  
        }    
    // Rename sheet  
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Directory Tool Full dump');

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5) 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Export-Directory Tool.xls"'); 
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $objWriter->save('php://output');  
    exit;  
    ?>
```

[image: desire output]

Comment: Have you set 0 to max_execution_time in php ini ?

Comment: in php.ini or in the above file???

Comment: You can set from  both ways from file as well php.ini

Comment: You can put this in your file ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

Comment: @LalitSharma still the same issue.. i have tried both ways :(

Comment: Try this ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0);       
ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1). If this not work then put you code in try catch and print error

Comment: set max_execution_time to unlimited(-1) is one solution but couple of things you are doing wrong first you can reduce code by using single query with join at same time instead two query.

Comment: @LalitSharma it didnt work :(

Comment: @kamlesh.bar i just added a picture for desired excel ouput.. the reason i use query like this is that there are more than one selection code for one personId plus i want them to join by ';'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something in one of those cell values that PHPExcel believes is a formula, ie a string value beginning with an `=`; but that isn't actually valid as an Excel formula, otherwise PHPExcel wouldn't be failing when trying to evaluate a formula.

You'll need to identify what that value is from the database, and ensure that you use the `setCellValueExplicit()` method to tell PHPExcel that it should be treated as a string and not as a formula